# Display German special characters

Tags: javascript

```
function($) {
$.fn.listnav = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.listnav.defaults, options);
var letters = ['_', 'a', 'ä', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l','m'
, 'n', 'o', 'ö', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'ü', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '-'];
```

AND

```
function createLettersHtml() {
var html = [];
 for (var i = 1; i < letters.length; i++) {
   if (html.length == 0) html.push('<a class="all" href="#">ALL</a><a class="_" 
       href="#">0-9</a>');
       html.push('<a class="' + letters[i] + '" href="#">' + ((letters[i] == '-') ?
       '...' : letters[i].toUpperCase()) + '</a>');
            }
```

AND

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" session="false"%>
```

The German Characters (ä, ö, ü), are displayed as ÃƑÂ, ÃƑÂ¶, ÃƑÂ¼

Do you know how can I fix this ?

Thank you !

---

FIXED:

```
if(letters[i] == 'ä') {
                    html.push('<a class="' + letters[i] + '" href="#">&Auml;</a>');
                }
                else if(letters[i] == 'ö') {
                    html.push('<a class="' + letters[i] + '" href="#">&Ouml;</a>');
                }
                else if(letters[i] == 'ü') {
                    html.push('<a class="' + letters[i] + '" href="#">&Uuml;</a>');
                }
                else {
                    html.push('<a class="' + letters[i] + '" href="#">' +  
     (letters[i].toUpperCase()) + '</a>');
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please add the solution as one of the answers and accept it. So that, people facing the same problem can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Is this PHP or ASP.NET?

Are the files where you store the üäö etc really UTF-8-encoded and delivered in that way to the browser? Or are they UTF-16 or some other encoding? I think your server serves them in some other encoding, and depending on if it is PHP or ASP.NET the fix would be different.

What about the German character `ß`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

This whole thing is regarding jQuery listnav: https://github.com/esteinborn/jquery-listnav

I just fixed the whole thing, you need to add a query in the a-z test:

```
function addLetterClass(firstChar, $el, isPrefix) {
            if ( /\W/.test(firstChar) ) {
                if (firstChar != "ä" && firstChar != "ö" && firstChar != "ü") {
                    firstChar = '-'; // not A-Z, a-z or 0-9, so considered "other"
                }
            }
```

So now "ä,ö,ü" don't get sorted out. :)